# Most Pythonic method of conditionally extracting data from multiple lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use two lists of dictionaries to build an object, the dictionaries are built from a TAP connection to two different databases. Because of the data sources I cannot guarantee that any of the dictionaries will contain the information I need, so I've chosen a primary dictionary and if the information is not in there then I extract it from the second dictionary.

Because I'm pulling the data from two different data sources, the field names from TAP differ for both sources, so I can't just do an intersection of the dictionaries.

At the moment I can get it to work, but I'm not happy with the solution:

```
for result in eeuresults:
    name=result['target_name']
    axes=result['semi_major_axis']
    period=result['period']
    radius=result['radius']

    if math.isnan(period):
        for r in eparesults:
            if r['pl_name'] == name: period=r['pl_orbper']
    if math.isnan(axes):
        for r in eparesults:
            if r['pl_name'] == name: axes=r['pl_orbsmax']        
    if math.isnan(radius):
        for r in eparesults:
            if r['pl_name'] == name: radius=r['pl_radj']
```

I've tried using dictionary.get() to make it simpler, but it falls down if the value isn't in the second list of dictionaries.

```
axes=result.get('semi_major_axis',[r['pl_orbper'] for r in eparesults if r['pl_name']==name][0])
```

Comment: What's wrong with the original?  I can actually understand what that means.

Comment: @topsail it is nice python, 1-line if statement, inline if-else is also 1-line

Comment: @topsail the fact that somebody writes a webpage and calls something pythonic does not mean it is pythonic

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to convert the `eparesults` to a `dict` to make the searching easier:

```
eeuresults = [
    {"target_name": "A", "semi_major_axis": 1, "period": 2},
    {"target_name": "B", "period": 3, "radius": 4},
]


eparesults = [
    {"pl_name": "A", "pl_orbper": 1, "pl_orbsmax": 2, "pl_radj": 3},
    {"pl_name": "B", "pl_orbper": 4, "pl_orbsmax": 5, "pl_radj": 6},
]

# This is the important part, convert `eparesults` to a dict:
eparesults_dict = {d["pl_name"]: d for d in eparesults}

for result in eeuresults:
    name = result["target_name"]
    axes = result.get("semi_major_axis", eparesults_dict.get(name, {}).get("pl_orbper"))
    period = result.get("period", eparesults_dict.get(name, {}).get("pl_orbsmax"))
    radius = result.get("radius", eparesults_dict.get(name, {}).get("pl_radj"))

    print(f"{name=} {axes=} {period=} {radius=}")
```

Prints:

```
name='A' axes=1 period=2 radius=3
name='B' axes=4 period=3 radius=4
```

Comment: That does appear to be a much cleaner solution than what I have - I like the double use of .get() to reduce loops and conditions!

Comment: Transcribing this to my script, I also noticed that I had pl_orbper and pl_orbsmax the wrong way around, so you accidently found a that I may have been using the wrong data (they two fields are related, so it's not that bad)!

Answer (score 1):

remove code duplication

```py
def find_in_eparesults(name, value, epa_key):
  if math.isnan(value):
    for r in eparesults:
      if r['pl_name'] == name:
        value = r[epa_key]
        break
  return value

for result in eeuresults:
    name=result['target_name']
    axes=find_in_eparesults(name, result['semi_major_axis'], 'pl_orbper')
    period=find_in_eparesults(name, result['period'], 'pl_orbsmax')
    radius=find_in_eparesults(name, result['radius'], 'pl_radj')
```

Comment: I'd push it a little further by using a dict {result_key: epa_key}

Comment: @Swifty if he does not use the mapping anywhere else a dict is overkill

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from math import nan, isnan

class Result(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return nan
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isnan(value):
            return
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.axes, self.period, self.radius))
    
results = defaultdict(Result)

for d in eeuresults:
    r = results[d['target_name']]
    r.axes   = d['semi_major_axis']
    r.period = d['period']
    r.radius = d['radius']
    
for d in eparesults:
    r = results[d['pl_name']]
    r.axes   = d['pl_orbsmax']
    r.period = d['pl_orbper']
    r.radius = d['pl_radj']

# In case you would need to lookup keys yourself, conversion to dict is needed.
# results = dict(results)
    
for name, (axes, period, radius) in results.items():
    print(f"{name=} {axes=} {period=} {radius=}")
```

This can take any number of lists as long as you know their keys.

Also you can extend behavior of `__setattr__` if you want any other comparison than `isnan`.

*If you expect missing keys from any of your dictionaries, then replace `d['key']` with `d.get('key', nan)`*

Comment: That's definitely an interesting and elegant way of solving it; though using a new object is a bit overkill and I need to then grab my data out of the dictionary to the object attributes I currently use.

I quite like it, but it's a bit too much for this project.

Comment: your logic is NOT identical to the OP code